# Trying to get score from Rotten Tomatoes URL

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to get original score from this link: https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/avengers_endgame/reviews

I am getting something returned, but it's not what I'm expecting. I'm getting a list of something like this:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e31633b4d123fff6432c6726cc26ad65", element="a9b96431-d527-4b79-8ddd-01d18f362cbd")>
```

(I just gave an example of one, but there is a list of these)

Here's what I'm using to get this result:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='row review_table_row']")
scores =[]
for row in rows:
    scores.append(row.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," review_desc ")]//div[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," small ")]'))
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with xpath?

[image: Just illustrate what I'm trying to get from this website]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a bit more specific XPath that ensures it contains a score in the first place

```
driver.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/avengers_endgame/reviews")
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='row review_table_row' and contains(., 'Original Score:')]")
```

then the extraction becomes easy

```
scores =[]
for row in rows:
    scores.append(row.text.split('Original Score: ')[1])
```

Out[20]:
['2.5/4.0',
'4/5',
'9/10',
'3/5',
'2.5/5',
'5 / 5',
'3.5/4',
'4/4',
'4/5',
'4/5',
'B+',
'3.5/4',
'B+',
'7/10',
'9/10']

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="small subtle review-link"]').get().split('Original Score: ')[1].split('\n')[0]
```

And the ending result would be:

'2.5/4.0'